# How to convert from CHAR to TIME in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a table with a column defined as `time CHAR(6)` with values like `'18:00'` which I need to convert from `char` to `time`.

I searched [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `::` syntax to cast the value:

```
SELECT my_column::time
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value really is a valid time, you can just cast it:

```
select '18:00'::time
```

Answer (score 1):

As said, you could use :: to cast, but you could also use the standard CAST() function:

```
SELECT CAST(my_column AS time) AS my_column_time
FROM   my_table;
```

This also works in other databases, not just PostgreSQL.